# Link for static page in CakePHP without appending the controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

So I created a couple of static pages in views > pages folder. They are contact.ctp and privacy.ctp. In my routes.php, I made it so that they could be viewed by going to domain.com/contact and domain.com/privacy with:

```
    Router::connect('/contact', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'contact'));

    Router::connect('/privacy', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'privacy'));
```

Now, when I link them at the footer with:

```
    <li><?= $this->Html->link('Contact', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'contact')); ?></a></li>

    <li><?= $this->Html->link('Privacy', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'privacy')); ?></a></li>
```

They are linked as domain.com/**pages**/terms. How can I stop it from appending the pages controller without giving an absolute url (i.e. without doing: `<?= $this->Html->link('Contact', 'http://www.domain.com/contact'); ?>` or is that the only other way?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a reason why your code is not working as it should (Cake 1.3 uses reverse routing to achieve exactly what you want). Have you modified any of the core? edit - cake even gives this example in the API: `Router::connect('/home-page', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));` so it would seem your code is ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you probably put these routes after `Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));` Just reverse that order and it should work.

Comment: Oh yeah! Lotta intricacies to learn with Cake, but I'm loving it the more I learn. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

## ROUTE

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

## VIEW

```
 echo $this->Html->link('Target', $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display', 'target', 'ext'=>'html')));
```

## OUPUT

```
<a href="target.html">Target</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an actual link?

```
<a href ="/contact">Contact</a>
```

And:

```
<a href ="/privacy">Privacy</a>
```

Short and sweet ^_^

Answer (score 0):

For SE posterity, and the sake of succinctness, you can use `Router::url( )`.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo Router::url('/contact'); ?>">Contact</a></li>
```